# After deployment: The stored procedure doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am trying to deploy an asp.net-mvc website.

On my local computer everything is ok, but when I am uploading to my server I am getting an error message

> *The stored procedure 'GetMenu' doesn't exist*

I restored the db from my local computer.

In the database the stored procedure `GetMenu` exists!

'GetMenu' is the first call for a stored procedure in the application.

I am using 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' with 'dbo_owner'

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: The first thing to check would be that you're connecting to the right database, and that there are no ownership/permissioning issues.

Comment: connection string is ok. I am using 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' widh dbo_owner

Comment: Try to connect to the db using the same user as the application does, and see what happens. (the `runas` command can help in impersonating built-in user accounts)

Comment: but are you connecting to the correct database? a lot of times people will accidentally create the procedure on the wrong database because the default is different than the application's database.

Comment: It's right in the connection string. do I need to check somewhere else? the db user can connect but cannot find the SP.

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework?  If so, did you recently change your model in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I had problem with the db user permissions!
I created a new db user and it works like a charm...

Thanks.